# Stock checking with coffeescipt

Tags: javascript

I have such cases:

stock status can be `in stock`, `undefined` (there is no such field in the object) or any other text

stock status is true if it is 'in stock' or undefined
all others are false

so this is my test object

```
obj = 
    one:
        stock: 'in stock'
    two:
        some: 'x'
    three:
        stock: 'not in stock blah blah any other text'
```

my method

```
stockCheck = (stock, msg) ->
    console.log {msg}
    return true if !stock or stock == 'in stock'
```

and some simply test

```
console.log stockCheck(obj.one.stock)?, 'should be in stock'
console.log stockCheck(obj.two.stock)?, 'should be in stock'
console.log stockCheck(obj.three.stock)?, 'should not be in stock'
```

is my code well for such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are issues with your test function, don't return `true`, just return the result of the test you're doing or your function won't return anything if the test is false:

```
stockCheck = (stock, msg) ->
    console.log {msg}
    return !stock or stock is 'in stock'
```

Also, why `{msg}`? Shouldn't it be just `console.log msg`?

Your `console.log` tests are erronous too, your function is supposed to do the test not you when you call it, remove the `?` from these lines:

```
console.log stockCheck(obj.one.stock) # true
console.log stockCheck(obj.two.stock) # true
console.log stockCheck(obj.three.stock) # false
```